# replace content via jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and have a simple question for you.
How to replace ".5" with ":30" in the below shown html "div" by using jquery?

```
    <div class="timepicker">
    <select>
    <option value="0" selected="selected">00</option>
    <option value="0.5">00.5</option><option value="1">01</option>
    <option value="1.5">01.5</option><option value="2">02</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what for you put there .5 when you need :30?

Comment: Do you need to change the value 0.5 or 00.5?

Comment: i'm makin this div through jquery, now i need to replace that .5 to :30 by using jquery only.

Comment: make divs with :30. what the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do (this works for the html, do you need the valuies too?):

```
$('option:contains(".5")').each(function(){
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace('.5', ':30'));

});
```

if you also need to replace the values:

```
$('option:contains(".5")').each(function(){
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace('.5', ':30'));
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace('.5', ':30'));              
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dwWXs/

Comment: Great, but yes nicole i need to the values too.

Comment: in this fiddle i also replace the values: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dwWXs/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('option[value="0.5"]').attr("value",".30");
$('option[value="0.5"]').html(".30");
```

Comment: @Jayantha This won't change 1.5 to 1:30 i think